# Lists with value semantics

Tags: javascript, node.js, list, collections

Is there any way in JavaScript – specifically, Node – to create lists with value semantics?

An example of what I mean:

```
> var s=new Set()
undefined
> s.add([1,2,3])
Set(1) { [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
> s.add([1,2,3])
Set(2) { [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

This demonstrates that JavaScript arrays have reference semantics, so different occurrences of [1,2,3] are different things. If they had value semantics, the set would've ended up containing only one element.

I know in this trivial case it could be done by converting to string, but I'm looking for a general solution that will work when the list elements don't have unique string representations.